# Exercise about substitution in nested lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Morning everyones!!!

I'm actually trying to make an exercise in Common Lisp but I have no idea of how to do it only using recursion.

This is the problem... I have nested lists and I have to substitute some elements in it. I have an example. This is my list:

list_one -> `(s ((1 2 t ((e 2 **x**) (4 3 **g**) (w 5 **e**))) (y 3 4 ((5 4 **u**))) (3 d 6 ((a 6 **r**) (8 5 **o**)))))`

The aim of the exercise is to substitute all the marked characters. This is only an example but the position of the marked characters is always the same in the nested list.

I have to substitute the marked characters with the values in another list (second_list):

second_list -> `(3 4 5 6 7 8)`

In this example the resulting list must be :

resulting_list -> `(s ((1 2 t ((e 2 **3**) (4 3 **4**) (w 5 **5**))) (y 3 4 ((5 4 **6**))) (3 d 6 ((a 6 **7**) (8 5 **8**)))))`

I read something similar on Internet but the solutions implemented are too difficult and I'm not able to implement them to myself. I'm looking for something that uses only recursion and my greatest problem is that even if I know the position of elements to substitute in the structure of the nested list I don't understand how to reach it.

Thank you to everyone!!

Comment: Try using [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/First_steps/Beginner_tutorial) site show your code.

Comment: I thought something using a function that reduce my list to one level but I wasn't able to procede because I can't discriminate between char and numberp and I also can't delete parenthesis!!